# Sort some apples!

Tags: code-challenge, sorting, restricted-complexity

### Problem

Imagine 7 buckets lined up in a row. Each bucket can contain at most 2 apples.
There are 13 apples labeled 1 through 13. They are distributed among the 7
buckets. For example,

```
{5,4}, {8,10}, {2,9}, {13,3}, {11,7}, {6,0}, {12,1}
```

Where 0 represents the empty space. The order in which the apples appear *within*
each bucket is not relevant (e.g. {5,4} is equivalent to {4,5}).

You can move any apple from one bucket to an adjacent bucket, provided there is
room in the destination bucket for another apple. Each move is described by the
number of the apple you wish to move (which is unambiguous because there is only one empty space). For example, applying the move

```
7
```

to the arrangement above would result in

```
{5,4}, {8,10}, {2,9}, {13,3}, {11,0}, {6,7}, {12,1}
```

### Objective

Write a program that reads an arrangement from STDIN and sorts it into the
following arrangement

```
{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10}, {11,12}, {13,0}
```

using as few moves as possible. Again, the order in which the apples appear 
*within* each bucket is not relevant. The order of the buckets does matter. It should output the moves used to sort each arrangement seperated by commas. For example,

```
13, 7, 6, ...
```

Your score is equal to the sum of the number of moves required to solve the following arrangements:

```
{8, 2}, {11, 13}, {3, 12}, {6, 10}, {4, 0}, {1, 7}, {9, 5}
{3, 1}, {6, 9}, {7, 8}, {2, 11}, {10, 5}, {13, 4}, {12, 0}
{0, 2}, {4, 13}, {1, 10}, {11, 6}, {7, 12}, {8, 5}, {9, 3}
{6, 9}, {2, 10}, {7, 4}, {1, 8}, {12, 0}, {5, 11}, {3, 13}
{4, 5}, {10, 3}, {6, 9}, {8, 13}, {0, 2}, {1, 7}, {12, 11}
{4, 2}, {10, 5}, {0, 7}, {9, 8}, {3, 13}, {1, 11}, {6, 12}
{9, 3}, {5, 4}, {0, 6}, {1, 7}, {12, 11}, {10, 2}, {8, 13}
{3, 4}, {10, 9}, {8, 12}, {2, 6}, {5, 1}, {11, 13}, {7, 0}
{10, 0}, {12, 2}, {3, 5}, {9, 11}, {1, 13}, {4, 8}, {7, 6}
{6, 1}, {3, 5}, {11, 12}, {2, 10}, {7, 4}, {13, 8}, {0, 9}
```

Yes, each of these arrangements has a solution.

### Rules

- Your solution must run in polynomial time in the number of buckets per move. The point is to use clever heuristics.
- All algorithms must be deterministic.
- In the event of a tie, the shortest byte count wins.

Comment: What's the point of denoting the destination when there is only one space you can move an apple to?

Comment: What if my brute-force solution runs in a reasonable amount of time? There are only 700M states - easily enumerable in the matter of minutes. Define "reasonable amount of time".

Comment: @JanDvorak Per "What's the point" - good call. That hadn't occurred to me. I'm defining *reasonable* here to be less than the amount of time required to brute force the solution ;)

Comment: Does your definition of "reasonable" mean we should first implement the brute-force solution, then anything that's faster counts?

Comment: Is final order of bucket important?

Comment: @JanDvorak Do you have any suggestions for how I could define a time limit that would prevent brute forcing a solution? Because this is about the best I've been able to think up.

Comment: @AMK Could you clarify? I don't understand your question. The order of the buckets is relevant.

Comment: @Orby This problem is still possible to solve optimally while staying faster than bruteforce. Not sure how much, but even a trivial heuristic for A* counts as faster than brute-force.

Comment: @Orby he means, is it allowed to have the buckets reordered as long as the correct apples are together?

Comment: I see, no the buckets cannot be reordered. I've clarified this in the question now.

Comment: @JanDvorak I certainly don't know how difficult it will be to solve optimally. I know that, in general, finding the shortest path in a [pebble motion problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebble_motion_problems) is NP-hard. I don't know if this particular one is. If it comes to it, it would be interesting to see some code golfed A* implementations.

Comment: @Orby you didn't specify the theoretical complexity of our algorithms, only they be faster than bruteforce

Comment: @JanDvorak I reiterate: Do you have any suggestions? This is not my area of expertise.

Comment: If you want golfed A*, keep it as is. I think they'll be fast enough - and golfing A* should be fun. A suggestion for future challenges would be (optimise x while keeping your theoretical complexity at O(f n)).

Comment: @JanDvorak Do you think polynomial time would be a reasonable constraint?

Comment: Please visit [our sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) the next time, where we can help smooth out your challenge before it's posted.

Comment: @JanDvorak Will do

Comment: @Orby depends on the challenge. Also note that you need an infinite family of inputs if you want to judge asymptotic complexity. Here, the generalisation is obvious, but I think a linear time per move would be really limiting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17120/discussion-between-orby-and-jan-dvorak).

Comment: Can input be in some other format?

Comment: @proudhaskeller So long as it isn't *dramatically* different, e.g. changing curly braces to brackets or adding extra brackets around the expression is fine. And make sure you specify the format in your solution.

Comment: @Orby: It's worth pointing out that finding the _optimal_ solution is NP hard. A simple bubble sort runs in O(n^2) and hence would be admissible as a solution.

Comment: @COTO Indeed. I was actually thinking of submitting it as a reference implementation.

Comment: @Orby damn. I thought I'd make it my contestant. Go ahead...

Comment: @JanDvorak Don't let me stop you :)

Comment: @Orby: You stipulate the algorithm must sort the list "using as few moves as possible" and in polynomial time, but you acknowledge that the problem of sorting the list using as few moves as possible is NP hard and hence can't (consistently) be solved in polynomial time. This leaves only the possibility of sorting the test lists in the fewest number of moves "by accident" (i.e. writing an algorithm in P that happens to realize the optimum for the test cases). Or when you say "as few moves as possible", do you mean "where rank is determined by fewest number of moves made"?

Comment: @COTO When I say, "as few moves as possible", I mean that the intention is to minimize the number of moves utilized. I realize that an optimum algorithm can't possibly execute in polynomial time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### C, <s>426</s> 448

This sorts apples one at a time from 1 to 13 similar to [yasen's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37760/31002), except whenever it has an opportunity to move a larger number up or a smaller number down, it will take it. <s>Sadly, this only improves performance on the first test problem, but its a small improvement.</s> I made a mistake when running the test problems. It seems I've simply reimplemented yasen's method.

```
#1: 62    #6: 40
#2: 32    #7: 38
#3: 46    #8: 50
#4: 50    #9: 54
#5: 40    #10: 36
```

It takes input without braces or commas, e.g.

```
8 2 11 13 3 12 6 10 4 0 1 7 9 5
```

Here is the golfed code coming in at 423 bytes counting a few unnecessary newlines (could probably be golfed more, but I expect this score to be beaten):

```
#define N 7
#define F(x,y) for(y=0;y<N*2;y++)if(A[y]==x)break;
#define S(x,y) x=x^y,y=x^y,x=x^y;
#define C(x,y) ((A[x*2]==y)||(A[x*2+1]==y))
A[N*2],i,j,d,t,b,a,n,s,v,u,w,g;main(){for(;i<N*2;i++)scanf("%d",A+i);g=1;while
(!v){F(0,i);b=i/2;F(g,u);w=u/2;d=b<w?1:-1;n=(b+d)*2;a=(b+d)*2+1;if(A[n]>A[a])
S(n,a);t=d-1?a:n;printf("%d,",A[t]);S(A[i],A[t]);while(C((g-1)/2,g))g++;v=1;for
(j=0;j<N*2;j++)if(!C(j/2,(j+1)%(N*2)))v=0;}}
```

And the ungolfed code, which also prints the score:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 7

int apples[N*2];

int find(int apple)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N*2; i++) {
        if (apples[i] == apple)
            return i;
    }    
}

void swap(int i, int j)
{
    int temp;
    temp = apples[i];
    apples[i] = apples[j];
    apples[j] = temp;
}

int contains(int bucket, int apple)
{
    if ((apples[bucket * 2] == apple) || (apples[bucket * 2 + 1] == apple))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int is_solved()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N * 2; i++) {
        j = (i + 1) % (N * 2);
        if (!contains(i / 2, j))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, dir, bucket, max, min, score;
    int target_i, target_bucket, target;

    /* Read the arrangement */
    for (i = 0; i < N*2; i++) {
        scanf("%d ", apples + i);
    }

    target = 1;
    while (1) {

        i = find(0);
        bucket = i / 2;
        target_i = find(target);
        target_bucket = target_i / 2;

        /* Change the direction of the sort if neccesary */
        if (bucket < target_bucket) dir = 1;
        else dir = -1;

        /* Find the biggest and smallest apple in the next bucket */
        if (apples[(bucket + dir) * 2] < apples[(bucket + dir) * 2 + 1]) {
            min = (bucket + dir) * 2;
            max = (bucket + dir) * 2 + 1;
        } else {
            min = (bucket + dir) * 2 + 1;
            max = (bucket + dir) * 2;
        }

        /* If we're going right, move the smallest apple. Otherwise move the
           biggest apple */
        if (dir == 1) {
            printf("%d, ", apples[min]);
            swap(i, min);
            score++;
        } else {
            printf("%d, ", apples[max]);
            swap(i, max);
            score++;
        }

        /* Find the next apple to sort */
        while (contains((target - 1) / 2, target))
            target++;

        /* If we've solved it then quit */
        if (is_solved())
            break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n", score);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Score: 448

My idea is to sort them consecutively, starting with 1. This gives us the nice property that when we want to move the space to the previous/next basket, we know exactly which of the two apples there we have to move - the max/min one, respectively. Here is the test breakdown:

```
#1: 62     #6: 40
#2: 32     #7: 38
#3: 46     #8: 50
#4: 50     #9: 54
#5: 40    #10: 36

Total score: 448 moves
```

The code can be golfed a lot more, but better quality of the code will motivate additional answers.

## C++ (501 bytes)

```
#include <cstdio>
#define S(a,b) a=a^b,b=a^b,a=a^b;
int n=14,a[14],i,j,c,g,p,q;
int l(int x){for(j=0;j<n;++j)if(a[j]==x)return j;}
int sw(int d){
    p=l(0);q=p+d;
    if(a[q]*d>a[q^1]*d)q^=1;
    printf("%d,", a[q]);
    S(a[q],a[p])
}
int main(){
    for(;j<n;scanf("%d", a+j),j++);
    for(;++i<n;){
        c=l(i)/2;g=(i-1)/2;
        if(c-g){
            while(l(0)/2+1<c)sw(2);
            while(l(0)/2>=c)sw(-2);
            while(l(i)/2>g){sw(2);if(l(i)/2>g){sw(-2);sw(-2);}}
        }
    }
}
```

Further improvements may be switching to C and trying to lower the score by starting from the large values downwards (and them eventually combining both solutions).

Comment: A substring of your code already forms a C program. Specifically, it could work in C by simply deleting the first line.

Comment: @feersum You're right. At the beginning, I had more C++ specific code, but after that with the switch to C in mind, it seems I got rid of it.

Comment: Could you specify that you've changed the input format in your solution to make it more clear to those who try to verify it?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 - 121

This implements a depth-first searching with increasing depth until it finds a solution. It uses a dictionary to store visited states so that it doesn't visit them again unless with a higher depth window. When deciding which states to check, it uses the number of misplaced elements as a heuristic, and only visits the best states possible. Note that since the order of the elements within their bucket does not matter, it always maintains an ordering within the buckets. This makes it easier to check if an element is misplaced.

The input is an array of ints, with the first int being the number of buckets.

So for instance, for #8 (this one takes a very long time to run on my machine, the others finish in seconds):

```
c:\python33\python.exe apples.py 7 3 4 10 9 8 12 2 6 5 1 11 13 7 0
```

Here are the results on the test set:
 #1: 12,
 #2: 12,
 #3: 12, 
 #4: 12,
 #5: 11,
 #6: 11,
 #7: 10,
 #8: 14,
 #9: 13,
 #10: 14

Here is the code:

```
import sys    

BUCKETS = int(sys.argv[1])    

# cleans a state up so it is in order
def compressState(someState):
  for i in range(BUCKETS):
    if(someState[2*i] > someState[2*i + 1]):
      temp = someState[2*i]
      someState[2*i] = someState[2*i + 1]
      someState[2*i + 1] = temp
  return someState    

state = compressState([int(x) for x in sys.argv[2:]])
print('Starting to solve', state)
WINNINGSTATE = [x for x in range(1, BUCKETS*2 - 1)]
WINNINGSTATE.append(0)
WINNINGSTATE.append(BUCKETS*2 - 1)
maxDepth = 1
winningMoves = []
triedStates = {}    

# does a depth-first search
def doSearch(curState, depthLimit):
  if(curState == WINNINGSTATE):
    return True
  if(depthLimit == 0):
    return False
  myMoves = getMoves(curState)
  statesToVisit = []
  for move in myMoves:
    newState = applyMove(curState, move)
    tns = tuple(newState)
    # do not visit a state again unless it is at a higher depth (more chances to win from it)
    if(not ((tns in triedStates) and (triedStates[tns] >= depthLimit))):
      triedStates[tns] = depthLimit
      statesToVisit.append((move, newState[:], stateScore(newState)))
  statesToVisit.sort(key=lambda stateAndScore: stateAndScore[2])
  for stv in statesToVisit:
    if(stv[2] > statesToVisit[0][2]):
      continue
    if(doSearch(stv[1], depthLimit - 1)):
      winningMoves.insert(0, stv[0])
      return True
  return False    

# gets the moves you can make from a given state
def getMoves(someState):
  # the only not-allowed moves involve the bucket with the 0
  allowedMoves = []
  for i in range(BUCKETS):
    if((someState[2*i] != 0) and (someState[2*i + 1] != 0)):
      allowedMoves.append(someState[2*i])
      allowedMoves.append(someState[2*i + 1])
  return allowedMoves    

# applies a move to a given state, returns a fresh copy of the new state
def applyMove(someState, aMove):
  newState = someState[:]
  for i in range(BUCKETS*2):
    if(newState[i] == 0):
      zIndex = i
    if(newState[i] == aMove):
      mIndex = i
  if(mIndex % 2 == 0):
    newState[mIndex] = 0
  else:
    newState[mIndex] = newState[mIndex-1]
    newState[mIndex-1] = 0
  newState[zIndex] = aMove
  if((zIndex % 2 == 0) and (newState[zIndex] > newState[zIndex+1])):
    newState[zIndex] = newState[zIndex+1]
    newState[zIndex+1] = aMove
  return newState    

# a heuristic for how far this state is from being sorted
def stateScore(someState):
  return sum([1 if someState[i] != WINNINGSTATE[i] else 0 for i in range(BUCKETS*2)])    

# go!
while(True):
  triedStates[tuple(state)] = maxDepth
  print('Trying depth', maxDepth)
  if(doSearch(state, maxDepth)):
    print('winning moves are: ', winningMoves)
    break
  maxDepth += 1
```

Comment: I've upvoted this because it is useful to see optimal solutions, but notice that this does not run in polynomial time in the number of buckets per move as required by the question. I don't believe that any algorithm which produces an optimal solution (in general) can run in polynomial time.

Comment: For the first test problem, your program generates 10, 8, 1, 12, 6, 7, 11, 3, 5, 13, 4, 9, which is not a valid solution. I think you may have misunderstood the question. Notice the question states that "You can move any apple from one bucket to an adjacent bucket" i.e. the bucket to the right or left of it (not an arbitrary bucket).

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the adjacency restriction! After I posted this I had a nagging suspicion that the running time restriction was violated too. I wasn't 100% sure as I was writing it, because the dynamic programming element of avoiding repeated states confused me. Thanks for the upvote even though this fails on two counts; this is a fun puzzle and I'll see if I can come up with a better, valid answer.